# Inserting time dimension into 2d array (lon, lat) to create 3d array (time,lat,lon)

Tags: array, concatenation

I'm trying to create a 3d array with 'time, lat, and lon' dimension. My data is from trmm 3b42 v7. Can someone help me with what should I do. The following are the codes I created.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import glob
import pandas as pd


for file in glob.glob('*.nc4'):
    data = Dataset(file,'r')
    precp = data.variables['precipitation']
a = np.array(precp)
b = a.astype(np.int64)

date = pd.date_range(start = "2010/1/1", periods = 3652)
c = date.strftime('%y%m%d, %r')
d = pd.DataFrame(date)
e = d.index.values
data1 = np.concatenate(e,b)
```

I get this error while running:

```
TypeError:only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```